# decimal Regex Expression issue

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regex in .NET that represents a decimal number with up to 9 digits to the left of the decimal point and 1 or 0 digits to the right. What I have isn't working.

Here is what I have:

```
@"^\d{0,9}[\.\d]{0,1}$"
```

What am I doing wrong? This regex is currently allowing 10 digits to the left of the decimal point and no digits to the right although it does accept strings like this -->  `12.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you have a character class `[\.\d]` and you are saying  :

please match one or zero of either a . or a digit.

What you really want to do however would be this :

```
^\d{0,9}(\.\d)?$
```

This says from the start of the string match 0 to 9 digits (maybe you need to do this {1,9} because as it stands now an empty string will also match), followed by maybe a dot with a digit and then the end of the string.

Comment: Good explanation - thank you. I'm still trying to perfect my understanding of regex.

Comment: A character class is a logic or. It matches a single character of all the characters inside it, in an unspecified order. So even [\.\d]{2} would have been wrong since it could match 2. or .. or .2 or 22. Accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I did. It makes you wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It should say

```
^\d{1,9}(\.\d)?$
```